# How to decide the best pair of random_state value and class labels?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

For the last few days, I was trying to implement the **KMeans** algorithm using **SciKit Learn**, But I came across a very confusing problem. I have a dataset that has two class labels `['ALL', 'AML']` where `ALL has 47` and `AML has 25` samples and `100` attributes to train from and now I want to use this dataset for KMeans clustering so that I can compare the predicted results with the original class labels. Before asking my question let me explain certain scenarios. In all the scenarios I have taken all the `100` attributes to fit the model.

**Scenario 1:**

In the first run, I started with a model that is created with pretty much default arguments i.e. `model = KMeans(n_clusters=2)`. For comparing the predicted class labels(which are *numeric*) with the original labels(which are *strings*), I set the original class labels as `ALL = 1` and `AML = 0`. After that, while comparing using a classification report I got an average accuracy of `35%`. Then I run the algorithm once again and got an accuracy of `44%`. For the third try, I got `33%` and so on.

However, I looked about it and came to know that the `random_state` argument needs to have a fixed value to get same accuracy throughout all runs.

**Scenario 2:**

After knowing about `random_state`, this time I started with random state 0 and created the model as `model = KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=0)` and kept the original class labels as before i.e `ALL as 1` and `AML as 0`. However, this time the output didn't change on different runs and  I got an accuracy of `53%`. But, out of curiosity, I swap the original class label i.e. I set `ALL as 0` and `AML as 1` which results in `47%`.

**Scenario 3:**

This time I choosed `random_state` as `1` i.e. `model = KMeans(n_cluster=2, random_state=1)` and having `ALL as 0` and `AML as 1` gave `67%` accuracy while considering `ALL as 1` and `AML as 0`
gave `33%` accuracy.

So, My question is what I am doing wrong here? Am I implementing something wrong? If I am right then why the result is changing so much depending on random_state and class labels? What's the solution and how to choose the best pair of random_state and class labels?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things at play here:

- The K-means class takes an `init` keyword argument which decides how to place the initial cluster centroids. The default is `k-means++` which is used in your case. The initial placement of the clusters depends on your class order. Keeping the random state the same and changing the class order will change in the initial placement of the clusters, therefore, changing the results.
- Changing random state will again change the initial placement of the clusters which will influence the final outcome.
- The reason you're probably getting inconsistent results is:

  - You have a high number of dimensions to your data (read up on the "Curse of dimensionality")
  - K-means works best on globular data and clusters of equal size!
  - If your data is anisotropically distributed I would not suspect good clusters. Take a look here at the [Sklearn page](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#overview-of-clustering-methods)

To potentially get around this I would perform dimensionality reduction on the data such as with UMAP or T-SNE and reduce down to two dimensions. This will allow you to plot the data and make it far easier to inspect what is going wrong.